# How to not use includeUncontrolled in clients.matchAll?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-push

In a service worker, I'm querying for clients.

```
event.waitUntil(
  clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true, type: 'window'})
  .then( windowClients => {
  // ...
  })
);
```

I can not figure out how to not use `includeUncontrolled: true`. Without it I get no results. I have tried using `clients.claim()` to no result.

```
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(clients.claim());
});
```

How to get a page under the control of a service worker? `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` is also `null` / `undefined`.

Comment: As far as I know, `includeUncontrolled` if set to true, the matching operation will return all service worker clients who share the same origin as the current service worker. Otherwise, it returns only the service worker clients controlled by the current service worker. There is no other alternative for this property.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably getting into service worker internals, but I wonder if the notification handling service worker will ever have clients, or if it is always a new instance.